# Seaborn: discrete colorbar

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a Dataframe which represents a binary matrix (0 and 1), with labels on rows and columns.
I'm using the following code to print the matrix assigning each label a color:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
N = 100

M = 200
p = 0.8
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (M,N), p=(p, 1-p)),
                  columns=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:N]),
                  index=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:M]))


cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(.8, .8, .8, 1.0)] + [plt.cm.jet(i) for i in range(plt.cm.jet.N-1)])

ax = sns.heatmap(df.apply(lambda s: (s.name==s.index)*s*(s.index+1)), mask=df.eq(0), cmap=cmap )
```

[image]

My problem is that the colormap is sequential, while I would like it to be discrete (I know the number of colors in advance).

When I try to switch from jet (sequential) to a descrete one:

```
N = 100
M = 200
p = 0.8

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0,1], (M,N), p=(p, 1-p)),

                  columns=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:N]),

                  index=sorted((list(range(10))*N)[0:M]))


cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(.8, .8, .8, 1.0)] + [plt.cm.tab20(i) for i in range(plt.cm.tab20.N-10)])

ax = sns.heatmap(df.apply(lambda s: (s.name==s.index)*s*(s.index+1)), mask=df.eq(0), cmap=cmap)
```

I get the grey color as an additional one in the colorbar (final color, at the bottom)[image]

Comment: Do you also want to pick the colors yourself?

Comment: I don't really care, as long as the colors are different enough

Comment: You get a continuous colormap because `plt.cm.jet.N` is 256.  You could select less colors. E.g. `ncols = df.index.max() + 1; cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap([(.8, .8, .8, 1.0)] + list(plt.cm.turbo(np.linspace(0, 1, ncols))))`.  In the example I also replaced `jet` by `turbo`, because [`jet` has a very bad reputation](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2014/10/16/how-bad-is-your-colormap/).

Comment: The main issue is the grey color that appears in the colorbar (I would like to hide it, since it does not represent a block, it is just a "background" color) when I switch to a discrete colormap. Your suggestion does not solve it, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

- the heatmap to be invisible where the original dataframe is zero
- the heatmap to be grey where the new dataframe is zero

You can use a `mask` to mask away the original zeros.  And use an [`under`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_under) color for the new zeros. `vmin` indicates the lowest valid value. Default, the under color isn't shown in the colorbar.

Optionally you can change the tick locations of the colorbar.

Here is an example:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 100
M = 200
p = 0.8
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], (M, N), p=(p, 1 - p)),
                  columns=sorted((list(range(10)) * N)[0:N]),
                  index=sorted((list(range(10)) * N)[0:M]))

ncols = df.index.max() + 1
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(plt.cm.turbo(np.linspace(0, 1, ncols)))
cmap.set_under((.8, .8, .8, 1.0))

ax = sns.heatmap(df.apply(lambda s: (s.name == s.index) * s * (s.index + 1)), mask=df.eq(0), cmap=cmap, vmin=1)

cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(1, ncols, 2 * ncols + 1)[1::2])
cbar.set_ticklabels(range(1, ncols + 1))

plt.show()
```

[image: sns.heatmap with filtered away values]

PS: To repeat a color, the list of colors can be edited. Here is an example:

```py
ncols = df.index.max() + 1
color_list = plt.cm.turbo(np.linspace(0, 1, ncols))
color_list[2] = color_list[3] # as an example, set the third color equal to the fourth
cmap = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
```

Comment: May I ask you an additional thing? What if I wanted two or more labels (blocks) to have the same color (knowing in advance which ones should go together)?

Comment: I updated the post with an example to repeat colors.  Note that indexing starts at zero.